# Sql Query to fetch latest credit limit and sum of balance

Tags: sql, sas

I have a table with month end date,credit card numbers,  credit limit, balances,etc.

I want to extract the latest credit limit and also sum the balances grouped by the credit card numbers.

I looking to write the query in sas using proc sql.

How do I do it?

Comment: Please include more information such as your overall table structure, data types, and PK/FK references.

Comment: The credit card number is the primary key.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should try this query hopefully you'll get expected result.

```
select sum(balance) as balance 
from table 
group by credit_card_no 
order by id desc
```

Comment: Looking for the latest credit limit as well

Comment: in the same query?

Comment: Yes, both the fields in the same query

Comment: I think you use subquery this one